# Jenkins API to retrieve a build log in chunks

Tags: jenkins, plugins

For a custom monitoring tool I need an API (REST) to fetch the console log of a Jenkins build in chunks.

I know about the /consoleText and /logText/progressive{Text|HTML} APIs, but the problem with this is that sometimes, our build logs get really huge (up to a few GB). I have not found any way using those existing APIs that avoids fetching and transferring the whole log in one piece. This then normally drives the Jenkins master out of memory.

I already have the Java code to efficiently fetch chunks from a file, and I have a basic Jenkins plugin that gets loaded correctly.

What I'm missing is the correct extension point so that I could call my plugin via REST, for example like

```
http://.../jenkins/job/<jobname>/<buildnr>/myPlugin/logChunk?start=1000&size=1000
```

Or also, if that is easier

```
http://.../jenkins/myPlugin/logChunk?start=1000&size=1000&job=<jobName>&build=<buildNr>
```

I tried to register my plugin with something like (that code below does not work!!)

```
@Extension
public class JobLogReaderAPI extends TransientActionFactory<T> implements Action {

    public void doLogChunk(StaplerRequest req, StaplerResponse rsp) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "## doLogFragment req: {}", req);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "## doLogFragment rsp: {}", rsp);
    }
```

But I failed to find the right encantation to register my plugin action.

Any tips or pointers to existing plugins where I can check how to register this?

Comment: I just found the DeleteLogPlugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/delete-log-plugin. This may be a very simple example for what I'm trying, I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed more simple than I expected :-) It as always: once one understands the plugin system, it just needs a few lines of code.

Turns out all I needed to do was write 2 very simple classes

The "action factory" that get's called by Jenkins and registers an action on the object in question (in my case a "build" or "run"

```
public class ActionFactory extends TransientBuildActionFactory {

    public Collection<? extends Action> createFor(Run target) {
        ArrayList<Action> actions = new ArrayList<Action>();
        if (target.getLogFile().exists()) {
            LogChunkReader newAction = new LogChunkReader(target);
            actions.add(newAction);
        }
        return actions;
    }
```

The class the implements the logic

```
public class LogChunkReader implements Action {
    private Run build;

    public LogChunkReader(Run build) {
        this.build = build;
    }

    public String getIconFileName() {
        return null;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return null;
    }

    public String getUrlName() {
        return "logChunk";
    }

    public Run getBuild() {
        return build;
    }

    public void doReadChunk(StaplerRequest req, StaplerResponse rsp) throws IOException, ServletException {
```